# returning struct* from a function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have following code

```
struct myStruct *struct_var;
struct myStruct * select_my_struct()
{
return struct_var;
}
some_function()
{
    myStruct=struct_create();//struct_create() is of return type struct myStruct *
    another_function(struct_var);   // line A
    another_function(select_my_struct()); //line B
}
```

My question is: do the *line A* and *line B* does the same thing?

Comment: Yes, they seem to be doing the same thing.

Comment: Is there any reason to doubt it?

Comment: @n.m. Most likely the OP is trying something else (that's not working) and posted this code as an example meant to be equivalent.

Comment: I am bit confused  with (afraid of) pointers. Thanks for quick response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct_var` is a pointer and `select_my_struct()` returns where `struct_var` points to.

So both of them are same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has the same declaration, as it takes a pointer to a mystruct datatype.